# Should the LSTM layer be the input layer or they should be 2 separate layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, sequential

I have this LSTM code in python:

```
model = Sequential(name="Activity_recognition_model")
model.add(LSTM(units, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

Note that n_features is the number of input featrures.

I need to draw the architecture of this NN. My questions:

1. Is the LSTM layer the input layer? or they should be 2 different layers?
2. Other layers would be 2 hidden layers and 1 output layer right?

Thanks,
Shosho

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `units` in the second line? Typically, LSTMs receive both external input, and their previous internal state as input.
2. yes that's right